# Android: background processing beside an active/sleeping activity + controlling that via start / stop

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent

What is the best alternative for running a task repeatedly even when the App is not active? The task should stop when the App has readlly exited.

1 - Besides my App I would like to perform a task that is executed whether my App is visible or paused / sleeping. So after some kind of event or time interval (for simplicity) the task is executed repeatedly.

2 - AND ... the App, when active, should be able to start/stop the task executed.

First option is using a Local Service.

```
public void enableTheTaskToBeRepeatedEach10seconds() { 
    enableTask = true; 
} 
public void disableTheTaskToBeRepeatedEach10seconds() { 
    enableTask = fasel; 
}
```

Local Service

```
public void onCreate() {
    readthread = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            try {
                Thread.sleep( 2000);
                if( enableTask ) { 
                    System.out.println( "+++++ DO task - here update counter ++++");
                    counter++;
                } else { 
                    System.out.println( "+++++ SKIP task - here update counter ++++");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        } });
    readthread.start(); 
}
```

Option 2: I see the BackgroundTask. I could create a Thread in it like the one above. Can I interact with the background task to start/stop?

Are there better options?

Comment: Why not use a regular Service?

Comment: What is the advantage of a regular service over a local service? 

Communication from the Activity to the (local) service is easier.
ANother advantage is that exiting the App will stop the service. In this case that is what I like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 2 weeks I have a good working Local Service. This is the rigth solution for me. 
When necessary I can stop it, so no battery energy is drained.